# any elasticsearch datatype matching decimal timestamp?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have a timestamp from log file like {"ts" : "1486418325.948487"}
My infrastructure are "filebeat" 5.2.0 --> "elasticsearch" 5.2

I tried mapping the "ts" to "date" -- "epoch_second" but es writing failed in filebeat.

```
PUT /auth_auditlog
{
  "mappings": {
    "auth-auditlogs": {
      "properties": {
        "ts": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The filebeat error msg like

```
WARN Can not index event (status=400): {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [ts]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"1486418325.948487\""}}
```

I tried use "1486418325" is ok so I guess es doesn't accept decimal format timestamp. However, python default output timestamp is this format.

My purpose is to type correctly in elasticsearch. I want to use ts as a original timestamp in elasticsearch.
Any solution is welcome except to change the original log data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filebeat doesn't have a processor for this type of stuff. You can't replace the `@timestamp` with the one your log has in Filebeat. What you can do, is send that stuff to logstash and let the `date` filter parse epoch.

```
date {
  match => ["timestamp","UNIX","UNIX_MS"]
}
```

---

The other option would be to use a ingest node. Although I haven't used this myself, it seems it is also able to do the job. Check out the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html).

Comment: Yep. With the 5.x series of ES, it comes with [a date processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/date-processor.html) to handle the `date {}` filter inside ES without resorting to a full blown logstash pipeline somewhere.